# How to use HTML5 in Netbeans?

Tags: html, netbeans

I'm developing a program, and wanted to use html/css/jsp in Netbeans for GUI because I used this program for my another JAVA project. It was very helpful for me to do GUI like JFrame, JButton etc..

Can I not use Netbeans like I did? There's no design part when I made a web application.

Answer (score 0):

[A simple tut for netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-gettingstarted.html)

The another resource you may need is
[visualwebdev](https://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/visualwebdev/)

Also html5 fun pack may come handy.

Comment: I downloaded HTML5 fun pack and got the packages of GUI (?) by reading two comments. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for drag and drop like java then netbeans not provide facility for web designing. There is no design part you have to code yourself for even a single buttotn.

Comment: I downloaded HTML5 fun pack and got the packages of GUI (?) by reading two comments. Thanks!!!